# Tamanho do Salto diferente em aparelhos Android Unity 5

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Criei um Jogo tipo `Infinite Runner` que funciona corretamente na aba Game da Unity 5 porém no android quando realizo o Jump em meu personagem ele tem uma subida sempre de tamanho diferente, como posso resolver este problema?

> **OBS:** O app foi testado em 2 Androids diferentes (4.4.2 e 5.0) (tiveram o erro em questão).

**Funções que realizam o Jump**

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    CheckPlayerInGround();
    MakeJump();
    animator.SetBool("jump", !steppingDown);
}

void CheckPlayerInGround(){
    steppingDown = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 0.2f, whatIsGround);
}

void MakeJump(){
    if(Input.touchCount > 0){

        if((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x < Screen.width / 2) && steppingDown){
            if(slide == true){
                UpdateColliderScenarioPosition(0.37f);
                slide = false;
            }
            audio.PlayOneShot(audioJump);
            audio.volume = 0.75f;
            playerRigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpPower * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e pelo que vi pode ter relação com o framerate tenta da uma olhada

Comment: Onde está definida `jumpPower`? Seu valor muda em algum lugar? E a função `UpdateColliderScenarioPosition`, o que ela faz? Por que ela recebe um parâmetro fixo com o valor 0,37? Sem esses detalhes, fica difícil saber onde pode haver um erro.

Comment: De todas as formas, você está misturando física com gerenciamento de frame rate. A Unity já faz isso pra você, quando você usa física. Tente tirar o `* Time.fixedDeltaTime` na multiplicação pela força do pulo.

Comment: @LuizVieira jumpPower esta definida pelo inspecor (2500f), ele não muda durante o jogo, UpdateColliderScenarioPosition para que o colidder salte e não trombre com as barreiras do cenario.

Comment: @LuizVieira sem o `* Time.fixedDeltaTime` o personagem sai da tela, para resolver baixei o `jumpPower` para 250 ma continuo saindo da tela (na aba editor da unity pula na altura adequada com 250 no jumpPower)

Comment: @LuizVieira para ficar com uma altura adequada no Android (4.4.2 e 5.0) mudei o `jumpPower` para 50 porem ainda fica uma inconsistência de altura dos saltos

Comment: Entendi. Bom, você chegou a colocar um [`Debug.Log`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) antes da linha que adiciona a força? Talvez no dispositivo real ele esteja sendo chamado muitas vezes seguidas, adicionando mais força do que o intencionado?

Comment: Os elementos aparecem no mesmo lugar no aparelho e no editor? É só o pulo que está com problemas? O problema deve estar relacionado com a resolução, dando a sensação que o pulo está maior ou menor. Qual a resolução que está configurado no editor (No topo da aba game, existe um select com várias opções) e qual a resolução do aparelho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver tal problema é necessário fazer duas mudanças:

**1)** Mudar a condição de pulo para:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
```

de modo que a ação de pulo só aconteça uma vez (ao primeiro instante que a tela for tocada).

**2)** Remover o `Time.fixedDeltaTime` para que sempre seja constante a altura do pulo do personagem.

Answer (score 0):

Quando se utiliza a movimentação dentro da Unity usando sua Física, não é necessário o Uso da Classe "Time" para multiplicar o valor do processador. No seu caso tente remover o "Time.fixedDeltaTime".

Comment: Você tem toda razão. Mas, a sua resposta só ficaria realmente boa se você explicasse também *o porquê* de isso não ser necessário. Se você fizer essa explicação direitinho, ganha o meu +1 (mesmo que o AP [já tenha mencionado em comentários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107399/tamanho-do-salto-diferente-em-aparelhos-android-unity-5#comment226219_107399) que essa correção não resolveu o problema dele).